# Analytically unramified local ring of dimension $1$ always admit canonical module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay, formal-completions, gorenstein

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a reduced local ring of dimension $1$ such that the completion of $R$ is also reduced (such rings are called [analytically unramified](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytically_unramified_ring)). Note that $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay since it is reduced and has dimension $1$.

My question is:

> Does $R$ necessarily admit a canonical module? I.e., is $R$ a homomorphic image of a local Gorenstein ring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $R$ necessarily has a canonical module. This is a special case of the following:

**Theorem** [[Herzog](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0059383), Satz 6.21]**.** *Let $R$ be a one-dimensional Cohen–Macaulay local ring. Then, the following statements are equivalent:*

1. *A canonical ideal exists.*
2. *For every minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of the completion $\hat{R}$ of $R$, the localization $\hat{R}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a Gorenstein ring.*